# Conditional Probability Help?

Tags: probability

> A standard deck of cards will be shuffled and then the cards will be turned
>   over one at a time until the first ace is revealed. Let $B$ be the event that the next card
>   in the deck will also be an ace.
>
> (a) Intuitively, how do you think $P(B)$ compares in size with $1/13$ (the overall proportion
>   of aces in a deck of cards)? Explain your intuition. (Give an intuitive discussion rather
>   than a mathematical calculation; the goal here is to describe your intuition explicitly.)
>
> (b) Let $C_j$ be the event that the first ace is at position $j$ in the deck. Find $P(B|C_j )$ in
>   terms of $j$, fully simplified.
>
> (c) Using the law of total probability, find an expression for $P(B)$ as a sum. (The sum
>   can be left unsimplified, but it should be something that could easily be computed in
>   software such as R that can calculate sums.)
>
> (d) Find a fully simplified expression for $P(B)$ using a symmetry argument.
>   Hint: If you were deciding whether to bet on the next card after the first ace being an
>   ace or to bet on the last card in the deck being an ace, would you have a preference?

Intuitively, it makes more sense that the probability of getting another ace is larger, since, after drawing one ace, $P(B) = 1/12$. However, I'm having issues determining the value of $C_j$. For instance, the probability that $C_j$ is at position $j$ is just $13/52$, right? There's only one place $j$, and there's only $13$ possible aces there.

Comment: Either way, though, P(B) is always smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B$ is the event that the first and second ace in the pack are adjacent.   Since we are only concerned with placement of the aces, consider a deck of 4 ace of hearts, and 48 jokers.

$C_j$ is the event that the *first* ace is at position $j$.   When given that event, there are $3$ remaining aces among the $52-j$ remaining cards, so the probability that one from these aces is the next card in the deck is: $\mathsf P(B\mid C_j) = \Box/\Box$

---

The Law of Total Probability says $\mathsf P(B)=\sum_{j=1}^{49} \mathsf P(C_j)\mathsf P(B\mid C_j)$.

We have $\mathsf P(B\mid C_j)$, so then, what is $\mathsf P(C_j)$?   The probability that the *first* ace will be at position $j$?

There are $\Box$ unbiased ways to select places in a deck of fifty two for four aces and of these, $\Box$ are ways to select places for the remaining aces among the places *after* position $j$.

Then put the sum together.

---

To find a simpler expression for $\mathsf P(B)$, we argue similarly.

There are $\Box$ unbiased ways to select places in a deck of fifty two for four aces and of these, $\Box$ are arrangements where the first and second ace are adjacent.

Therefore $\mathsf P(B)= \Box/\Box $?

Answer (score 0):

You don't know how many cards you've drawn before drawing the first ace, and since cards are inanimate they have no memory. Thus it'd only depend on the remaining number of cards. \
You aren't supposed to determine the value of Cj. Instead you should try to determine the probability of drawing an ace, given that there are 3 aces and 52-j cards left, i.e. $P(B|C_j)$

Comment: So, then, would the probability of P(B|Cj^c) be 4/(53-j)?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this,

Let's arrange cards,

No of ways to arrange cards$=52!$

Let's now arrange cards such that one ace is at $j^{th}$ position,

No of ways of selecting a ace from 4 aces to be at $j^{th}$ position$=4$

No of ways of arranging the other cards fixing the $j^{th}$ position$=51!$

Total no of ways that an ace is on $j^{th}$ position$=4×51!$

Now the probability of $C_j=\frac{4×51!}{52!}=\frac{4}{52}$

> Another possible argument,

Suppose the card at $j^{th}$ be $X$

Total no of possible $X=52$

No of cases we want (aces)$=4$

Hence,$$C_j=\frac{4}{52}$$

Comment: Am I correct, though, assuming then that Cj|B = 3/51?

Comment: We can apply the same argument,

Comment: I will explain more

Comment: Suppose the card at $j^{th}$ and the next position are $X$,$Y$

Comment: So $X$ can be anyone of $51$ other cards (minus the ace at $Y$)

Comment: So total no of outcomes for $X=51$

Comment: No of outcomes we want $X=3$

Comment: So probability is $=\frac{3}{51}$

Comment: @Yilan B. Bingo! Your answer is right.

Comment: No, @neonpokharkar .  If the *first* ace is at position $j$ then all of the remaining three aces are somewhere among the $52-j$ cards *after* that first ace.